# Nutch is not parsing the entire website, only the first URL

Tags: java, nutch

I'm trying to use Nutch `Fetcher` to fetch the entire website, but it only loads the first URL:

```
import org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher;
new Fetcher(conf).fetch(segment, 1);
```

This is what I see in the log:

```
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: starting at 2019-03-29 00:11:47
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: segment: /var/folders/vl/633jwjvn2jvbj9zfg1sgglhw0000gp/T/1198814103175176756/segments/20190329001146
[WARN] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetchItemQueues: Using queue mode : byHost
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: threads: 1
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: time-out divisor: 2
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.QueueFeeder: QueueFeeder finished: total 1 records hit by time limit : 0
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.net.URLExemptionFilters: Found 0 extensions at point:'org.apache.nutch.net.URLExemptionFilter'
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread: FetcherThread 129 Using queue mode : byHost
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread: FetcherThread 133 fetching http://www.zerocracy.com/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.RobotRulesParser: robots.txt whitelist not configured.
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.proxy.host = null
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.proxy.port = 8080
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.proxy.exception.list = false
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.timeout = 10000
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.content.limit = 65536
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.agent = yc/Nutch-1.15
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.accept.language = en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.Http: http.enable.cookie.header = true
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread: FetcherThread 133 has no more work available
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread: FetcherThread 133 -finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: -activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=0
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: -activeThreads=0
[INFO] org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: finished at 2019-03-29 00:11:49, elapsed: 00:00:02
```

What am I missing? It's Nutch 1.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Fetcher` class is only responsible of fetching/downloading the URLs present in the segment, using a configured number of threads. This translates into the fetcher not parsing or extracting URLs out of the fetched content. The `fetch` method only downloads the content, nothing more. For your use case you would need to parse the HTML content by your self (or using the `org/apache/nutch/parse` tools) and generate a new segment for fetching the newly discovered links.

This is how usually Nutch works, you provide one or more seed URLs. This URLs are fetched/parsed and the new discovered links are stored for the next iteration.

Comment: Hm... sounds a bit weird. How many iterations will I have? Can you please provide a link to some tutorial explaining this concept? All articles that I've seen so far suggest me doing generate+fetch+parse+dump and that's it. One iteration and the entire website is supposed to be here.

Comment: Exactly, what you described is the normal cycle: generate/fetch/parse/update, this is what the `bin/crawl` script does (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/bin/crawl#L340-L352). The issue is that fetch is only the step of downloading the content, nothing more. The link extraction from the raw HTML happens on the `parse` step, then the crawldb is updated and the new links can go then through the same cycle.

Comment: One more thing it is very difficult to do an entire website in one cycle. Not even in multiple cycles. Nutch doesn't have any way of knowing how many links it will be found on a website. This is restricted either by specifying how many URLs do you want to fetch or how "deep" the crawl should go.